# Inheritance of private methods

Tags: java, inheritance

Why the output of this program is:

```
person
person
```

I know that the inheritance means that the subclass take the properties of the superclass, here is the code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Person().printPerson();
        new Student().printPerson();
    }
}

class Student extends Person {
    private String getInfo() {
        return "Student";
    }
}

class Person {
    private String getInfo() {
        return "Person";
    }

    public void printPerson() {
        System.out.println(getInfo());
    }
}
```

I know that `getinfo()` method is not inherited and not overridden because it is `private`. But, there is another method in `Student` class that has the same name and returns `Student`.

I want to know why that is happening? How JVM works with inheritance exactly?

Comment: Well, the answer is that the `getinfo()` method is not inherited and not overridden because it's private.  But you said you know that already.  So what's your question exactly?

Comment: Why do you think that `printPerson` would be able to "reach" `Student#getInfo()`? The only method it can "see" (and correctly use) is `Person#getInfo()`.

Comment: you are hiding the method

Comment: @Tom .... Student class able to use printperson() method ,, and inside it System.out.println(getInfo()); ,, theres  getinfo() in student class too , i want to know why not using it instead of the methods in person class?

Comment: second **Person**  got printed because , `printPerson()` is inherited by student class and from `printPerson()`, we are calling `getinfo()` , because `printPerson()` method is define inside **Person** class , so `Person#getInfo()`  will be called

Comment: Just because `Student` is able to use methods of `Person` doesn't it also works the other way around.

Comment: `Person#printPerson` doesn't call `Student#getInfo` because `Person#getInfo` has not been overridden.  Because it's private.